# Manipulando el DOM

Tags: javascript

tengo un caso particular donde necesito aplicar un poco de JS a un Wordpress, sucede que necesita agregar un ancle de whatsapp que permitiera compartir una entrada al igual que otros anclajes dentro de un post, lo que sucede es que este theme no tiene en los post el compartir con whatsapp: Que fue lo que hice? pues manipule el DOM y agregue el dicho anclaje así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ok ahora lo que necesito es agregar el Atributo "onclick" con window.open("y el enlace del "href" que tenia allí dentro y no consigo como hacerle; GRAN RETO NO?") de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es lo máximo que he podido conseguir con este código:

```
const a = document.querySelector(".share-wabtn");
const b = a.getAttribute("href");
a.setAttribute("onclick", b);
```

Comment: NO funciona de esta manera? a.setAttribute("onclick", "window.open("+b+")");

Comment: Nada, no me funciona de esa manera amigo.